# Compare-Object - How do I know which is the difference object and which is the reference object?

Tags: powershell

I have two objects and want to compare them to find users found in both.
The below appeared to work OK until I tested the output. I found that although the number of users returned was correct, the actual values weren't.

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $PilotUsers -DifferenceObject $Leavers -IncludeEqual |
                        Where-Object {$_.sideindicator -eq '=='}
```

If I switch the ref and dif objects around I get the correct result. As I'm only interested in users in both I don't see how it matters which way around they are set. Clearly there is a need to understand how this works for future occasions.  Searches online haven't shed any light on this unfortunately.

My objects are created as below. Both return a pscustomobject with one property.

```
$PilotUsers = Get-aduser -Filter * -Properties memberof |
                Select-Object  samaccountname, memberof | 
                Where-Object {$_.memberof -like "*Licensing_Pilot Users*"}|
                Select-Object @{n='ID'; e={$_.samaccountname}} 

$Leavers = Import-Csv -Path $LeaverFile.FileName |
                Select-Object @{n='ID'; e={$_.payroll.substring(2,5).trimstart('0')}}
```

Please can someone explain or point me in the right direction?  The ultimate goal is to delete users found in the leavers object from the AD group object.

Comment: You seem to be comparing apples and oranges - your reference collection is an array of objects with properties `samaccountname` and `memberof`, diff collection is an array of objects with a single `ID` property ...

Comment: Sorry, lost a bit of code creating the MRE.  Amended above.  I created the calculated property in case I needed it for comparison by property.  I know I could have just selected samaccountname.

Comment: Is there a specific need to use `Compare-Object` here? This can be easily done with `.where({ })` or `where-object`

Comment: @Santiago No specific need.  I'd successfully used Compare-Object before and thought it simple enough; until now!  How would I go about using .where({ }) or where-object please?  Can you point me in the right direction please?  If it involves -contains, I've never had much luck with that.

Comment: Sure, I can post an example, can I assume that `ID` in `$Leavers` contains samAccountName of the users?

Comment: If you wanna compare the `ID` property on `$pilotUsers` vs the `ID` property on `$leavers` there must be some correlation between the two, that's what I meant.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Yes, sure does. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the property name you want to use for the comparison, in this case `-Property ID`:

```
# Emulating your data sets
$ref = 1..10|Select @{Name='ID';Expression={"$_"}}
$dif = 6..15|Select @{Name='ID';Expression={"$_"}}

# This will return pure nonsense
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $ref -DifferenceObject $dif -IncludeEqual |
                        Where-Object {$_.sideindicator -eq '=='}

# This will return the results you're expecting
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $ref -DifferenceObject $dif -IncludeEqual -Property ID |
                        Where-Object {$_.sideindicator -eq '=='}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. In the past I've only compared content of files and that has been fine without using -property.  Am I to take it that I should use -property whenever the object has a distinct property?  Bizarrely, the return that I did get was correct in value though the formatting was @{id-123} == .  Using your solution saved me having to expand the returned values to use them.  Still not sure why the returned values would be different dependent on which object was used as ref and which used as dif.  Using your emulated data creates conflicting results when not using -property.

Comment: @TonyW "your emulated data creates conflicting results when not using -property" - Yes, that's why the comment right above it says "This will return pure nonsense" :)

Comment: WRT comparing file contents - that works without an explicit property name because two strings can already meaningfully be compared by value

Comment: I appreciate that but in my simplistic world I'd have thought comparing a single digit with a single digit would simply result in left, right or both. There are no other properties to confuse the comparison. I'm just trying to understand what is going on with the comparison.  I understand your solution works and I will use it. Thanks

Comment: Except you're not comparing strings of digits - you're comparing objects that happen to have properties with strings of digits as their value - so PowerShell goes "ref collection had 10 [custom objects] and so did the difference collection" - so it just returns to ref collection as "equal output"

Comment: I guess I need a more in depth explanation of how Compare-Object works than can be provided in these comments. If you know of a good source could you post it here please?  If not I'll trawl online to see if I can find one.  There doesn't appear to be too many that explain how it works, they just attempt to explain how to use it.

Comment: @TonyW My naive explanation would be: Compare-Object does just that: it compares objects. If the objects are not a simple string or integer, but objects with properties, let's say a Name and ID, you have to tell Compare-Object what property you want to compare.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your query for `$pilotUsers` is highly inefficient. The right syntax for the query should be:

```
$PilotUsers = Get-ADuser -Filter * -Properties MemberOf |
              Where-Object {$_.memberof -like "*Licensing_Pilot Users*"} |
              Select-Object @{n='ID'; e={$_.samaccountname}}
```

A more efficient way to search for users that are direct members (non recursive) of groups with name `like` **Licensing_Pilot Users** is this:

```
$PilotUsers = Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like "*Licensing_Pilot Users*"} | Get-ADGroupMember |
              Where-Object {$_.ObjectClass -eq 'user'} |
              Select-Object @{n='ID'; e={$_.samaccountname}}
```

Now for the comparison, I will assume that you're getting a list of `sAMAccountNames` from your CSV file. This is how you can filter both variables to find the results you want.

```
# To get all pilotUsers that are in leavers
$pilotUsers.ID | Where-Object {$_ -in $leavers.ID}
$pilotUsers.ID.Where({$_ -in $leavers.ID})

# To get all leavers that are in pilotUsers
$leavers.ID | Where-Object {$_ -in $pilotUsers.ID}
$leavers.ID.Where({$_ -in $pilotUsers.ID})

# To get all users that are in both arrays
@(
    $pilotUsers.ID | Where-Object {$_ -in $leavers.ID}
    $leavers.ID | Where-Object {$_ -in $pilotUsers.ID}
) | select -Unique
```

Comment: That looks a whole lot easier to understand than Compare-Object. I'm sure Compare-Object has it's place but this looks just the job for my current requirement. I've not seen the .Where before; something to look into.  My original query has to run the way it is coded as the more efficient way times out.  Online searches suggest this is due to 'errors' in AD.  Something I can't and have no desire to look into.  Thanks.